# Different results from Murmur3 from Scala and Guava

Tags: scala, guava, consistent-hashing, murmurhash

I am trying to generate hashes using the Murmur3 algorithm. The hashes are consistent but they are different values being returned by Scala and Guava.

```
class package$Test extends FunSuite {
  test("Generate hashes") {
    println(s"Seed = ${MurmurHash3.stringSeed}")
    val vs = Set("abc", "test", "bucket", 111.toString)
    vs.foreach { x =>
      println(s"[SCALA] Hash for $x = ${MurmurHash3.stringHash(x).abs % 1000}")
      println(s"[GUAVA] Hash for $x = ${Hashing.murmur3_32().hashString(x).asInt().abs % 1000}")
      println(s"[GUAVA with seed] Hash for $x = ${Hashing.murmur3_32(MurmurHash3.stringSeed).hashString(x).asInt().abs % 1000}")
      println()
    }
  }
}


Seed = -137723950
[SCALA] Hash for abc = 174
[GUAVA] Hash for abc = 419
[GUAVA with seed] Hash for abc = 195

[SCALA] Hash for test = 588
[GUAVA] Hash for test = 292
[GUAVA with seed] Hash for test = 714

[SCALA] Hash for bucket = 413
[GUAVA] Hash for bucket = 22
[GUAVA with seed] Hash for bucket = 414

[SCALA] Hash for 111 = 250
[GUAVA] Hash for 111 = 317
[GUAVA with seed] Hash for 111 = 958
```

Why am I getting different hashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like Scala's `hashString` converts pairs of UTF-16 `char`s to `int`s differently than Guava's `hashUnencodedChars` (`hashString` with no `Charset` was renamed to that).

Scala:

```
val data = (str.charAt(i) << 16) + str.charAt(i + 1)
```

Guava:

```
int k1 = input.charAt(i - 1) | (input.charAt(i) << 16);
```

In Guava, the `char` at an index `i` becomes the 16 least significant bits of the the `int` and the `char` at `i + 1` becomes the most significant 16 bits. In the Scala implementation, that's reversed: the `char` at `i` is the *most* significant while the `char` at `i + 1` is the *least* significant. (The fact that the Scala implementation uses `+` rather than `|` could also be significant I imagine.)

Note that the Guava implementation is equivalent to using `ByteBuffer.putChar(c)` twice to put two characters into a little endian `ByteBuffer`, then using `ByteBuffer.getInt()` to get an int value back out. The Guava implementation is *also* equivalent to encoding the characters to bytes using `UTF-16LE` and hashing those bytes. The Scala implementation is not equivalent to encoding the string in any of the standard charsets that JVMs are required to support. In general, I'm not sure what precedent (if any) Scala has for doing it the way it does.

**Edit:**

The Scala implementation does another thing different than the Guava implementation as well: it passes the number of *chars* being hashed to the `finalizeHash` method where Guava's implementation passes the number of *bytes* to the equivalent `fmix` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Doesn't Murmur3 specify which bits to use? I was expecting a standard way of doing this.

Comment: @Saket: As far as the bits go, I think this boils down to an endianness thing. Guava specifies that it uses the _little-endian_ variant of the murmur3 algorithm, and the method it uses to combine two characters is equivalent to putting 2 consecutive `char`s into a `LITTLE_ENDIAN ByteBuffer` and getting an `int` out. Meanwhile the Scala version seems to be equivalent to putting 2 `char`s into a `BIG_ENDIAN ByteBuffer` and getting an `int` out. The issue of Scala passing the number of `char`s to `finalizeHash` rather than the number of bytes seems just wrong from what I can tell though.

Comment: (Looking at the C++ [implementation](https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/source/browse/trunk/MurmurHash3.cpp#94) of MurmurHash3_x86_32, it seems clear that the `len` parameter is the number of bytes to be processed in the data, and it's that `len` that is xor'ed with `h1` as part of the finalization step.)

Answer (score -1):

I believe `hashString(x, StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE)` should match Scala's behavior. Let us know.

(Also, please upgrade your Guava to something newer!)

Comment: This actually doesn't work since it only changes the order of bytes for each `char`; it doesn't change the order in which those chars are interpreted as an int.

Comment: Huh, I had thought that part *wasn't* different between the two.